# WPF, Caliburn Micro Bind Database record to VM

Tags: c#, wpf

Once again struggling with WPF and Caliburn Micro. I want to bind a DB record to the view if the record exists. However after retrieving the record, the view is not updated with the retrieved fields. Below is similar code am using:

View:

```
<TextBox x:Name="personId" Margin="114,12,288,281" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Retrieve" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="firstName" />
<TextBox x:Name="lastName" />
```

ViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
internal class PersonViewModel
{
    public string personId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }


    public void Retrieve()
    {
       try
            {
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    var q = con.Query<PersonViewModel>("select firstName,lastName from Person where id = @id", new {id = personId}).First();
                    MessageBox.Show("Succesfully retrieved " + q.firstName + " "  +  q.lastName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error retrieving due to {0}", x.Message);
            }
    }
```

}

The `Retrieve` method is firing and am getting the results in the `MessageBox`. However the View is not updated. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is retrieved from the database into `q`. You need to copy the data into the `personId`, `firstName` etc properties. When you update the properties, the property changed notification will then update the view.

Something like this:

```
   public void Retrieve()
    {
       try
            {
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    var q = con.Query<PersonViewModel>("select firstName,lastName from Person where id = @id", new {id = personId}).First();
                    // Copy database data into the local properties so they will update the view...
                    this.personId = q.personId;
                    this.firstName = q.firstName;
                    ...
                    MessageBox.Show("Succesfully retrieved " + q.firstName + " "  +  q.lastName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error retrieving due to {0}", x.Message);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought of this, but is there anyway to automatically bind it as am using Dapper with the ViewModel.

Comment: I've not found a good solution for copying the data yet. Manually retrieving it and copying isn't usually too onerous.

Comment: The issue is I have some ViewModels that contain more than 20 fields. Anyway will accept your answer as did not specify automatic binding.

Comment: May be worth looking at AutoMapper but you may find it quite complex.

Answer (score 2):

You have unclear separation of model and viewmodel concerns.
I would implement your scenario like this:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class PersonDetailsPageViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public void Retrieve()
    {
       try
       {
          using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
          {
              Person = con.Query<Person>("select firstName,lastName from Person where id = @id", new {id = personId}).First();
          }
       }
       catch (SqlException ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("error retrieving due to {0}", ex.Message);
       }
    }
}
```